# How can I import multiple .sql files into MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In my folder, I have a lot of *.sql files... How via one command I can import them?

For example; is something like this possible?

```
mysql -u root -p db_development < *.sql
```

If not, how can I import every .sql file into MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the best one-line I know:

```
for SQL in *.sql; do DB=${SQL/\.sql/}; mysql $DB < $SQL; done
```

or with password:

```
for SQL in *.sql; do DB=${SQL/\.sql/}; mysql -u user --password=11111 $DB < $SQL; done"
```

Warning: the password is plain text so visible when using 'ps'.

Comment: hm, and where to put here login, password and db?

Comment: in the conf file in /etc? or otherwise put it behind the mysql command.

Comment: what if i have multiple db names? will this be ok? for SQL in *.sql; do DB=${SQL/\db_development/}; mysql -u user --password=11111 $DB < $SQL; done"

Comment: the database is in the import file.

Comment: hm, but how to be if name is other?

Comment: Thanks saved a lot of time for me

Answer (score 6):

```
cat *.sql | mysql -u root -p db_development
```

This will ask one time for the password.

If the statements belong to different databases, insert a `USE databasename;` at the top of all .sql files.

Comment: how to add all sql files in sequence with respect to their names ?